# Integromat can't find Field Maps designer attachments

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I would like to make automatic email sending based on the updated value in Field Maps Designer.

Unfortunately, I cannot come across the problem displayed in the image below:

[image]

which clearly shows, that there is no option for picking up an attachment from the Field Maps Designer,

There is some hint here:

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-field-maps-questions/field-maps-attachments-and-make-integromat/td-p/1290800

but it didn't help me.

Is there anyone, who could advise on this scope? Is there something extra I could do with the Integromat to make the attachments sendable by email?

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Comment: Somewhat yes as you need to put the HTML code inside. I saw some integromat questions earlier here.

Comment: the presence of other off-topic questions doesn't legitimate new off-topic questions. If you think yours is on-topic, then explain it in the post how you are looking to code, or your actual code, etc. Otherwise, find the the dedicated SE site

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking to access the attachment from ArcGIS Field Maps. As correctly pointed out in the esri community discussion, the attachments are not directly available through the ArcGIS connection on Make/Integromat. However, they can be accessed through an API call set up through Integromat. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I don't understand the URL connection. It's different for any single image.
Should I use just 
https://services.arcgis.com/|
which refers to the attachment?

Comment: Here is the details of the API endpoint that you need to hit on Make: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-attachments-feature-service-layer-.htm

Comment: @Geographos I would love to claim the bounty. Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind showing me the live example of how the thing could work, that would be the best I guess.

Comment: you can connect with me on likedin (check bio).

Comment: are so many profiles under your name.

Comment: Check my stackoverflow bio.

Comment: I can't invite you